# How to set environment variables in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set environment variables through ansible playbook to install gnucobol with vbisam. But that variables are not getting set while executing playbook.

```
 name: Setting variables for CPPFLAGS
 shell: "echo $CPPFLAGS"
 environment:
  CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/vbisam-2.0/include

 name: Setting variables for LDFLAGS
 shell: "echo $LDFLAGS"
 environment:
  LDFLAGS: -L/opt/vbisam-2.0/lib

 name: Setting variables for LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 shell: "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
 environment:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/vbisam-2.0/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Can some one help me to fix the issue.

Comment: How do you know they are not getting set, if you don't check the results? Besides, you are aware how environment variables work in a system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your environment variables are definitely getting set.  Your existing tasks don't contain any attempt to *verify* this, so let's add one.  For example, if we run this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    -  name: Setting variables for CPPFLAGS
       shell: "echo $CPPFLAGS"
       environment:
         CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/vbisam-2.0/include
       register: cppflags

    - debug:
        var: cppflags.stdout
```

We see as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Setting variables for CPPFLAGS] **********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cppflags.stdout": "-I/opt/vbisam-2.0/include"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As @techraf hinted in a comment, it's important to understand that setting environment variables using the `environment` on a task sets them **only** for that task.  That is, if you wanted  `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` all set at the same time, you would need to do something like:

```
    -  name: Setting variables for CPPFLAGS
       shell: "echo $CPPFLAGS"
       environment:
         CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/vbisam-2.0/include
         LDFLAGS: -L/opt/vbisam-2.0/lib
         LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/vbisam-2.0/include
       register: cppflags
```

If you need those variables set on *multiple* tasks, you would need to either apply the same `environment` keyword to each task, or set `environment` on the play instead of individual tasks.

Comment: Hey, -1 person, any comments on how I can improve this answer?

Comment: @larsks, sorry, I don't know how It happaned. Maybe I accidentally hit the button 'downvote', but now I can't fix my mistake, before you changed you answer. Sorry again)